# Retrieving a list of values ​in a loop for later use in the IN statement. Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

How can you get a list of values ​​in a loop so that you can use it in the IN operator?
It turns out that I need to declare the desired type, assign a list of values ​​to the variable and use it in the IN operator

```
 DO $$
declare
rec record;
v_id ?;--Declare the correct type
begin
  for rec in (select id_field 
                from my_tbl
                )
    loop
        
        v_id = rec.id_field; --This should be getting a list of values
    
    end loop; 
   
   for rec_new in (select new_id_field 
                from new_my_tbl
                where id_field in(v_id)--Here's the use of the resulting list
                )
    loop
        
        .....
    
    end loop; 
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: You are going in the correct way

Answer (score 1):

Loops are always slower. Some years Tom Kyte, Senior Technical Architect (retired) at Oracle coined the phrase *Slow by Slow* processing. It is still appropriate. This is especially true here as this can be done in **a single statement**.

```
select new_id_field 
  from new_my_tbl
 where id_field in (select id_field 
                      from my_tbl
                   );
```

If you need the loop for additional processing then *inbed* that query in a cursor. See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html).

Comment: I'm interested in creating a list of records in a loop that I can use in the IN statement.
That's why my example is with loops. I am not interested in receiving data in any other way

Answer (score 0):

Loops are generally less performant than other methods.  In this case you could define an array variable, populate it with targeted `id_field` values , then use it later with an IN statement.

Comment: give an example

Comment: @Ambasador [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) are many